# TFS commit best practice?

Tags: version-control, tfs

In my previous jobs, programmers were encouraged to check-in code often with comments. At my new job now, the rule is that no one checks in anything until his or her code is QA'ed.  But because QA lags so much behind, we could rarely check-in. We can probably check in once every 2 weeks or so.  And when we are asked to check in, it is really a pain in the neck to sort out what's changed for which ticket that needs to be checked in. Do you guys understand the pain? And the consequence is that very often, we programmers forget to check in some important files for some ticket. Another consequence is that this: I have modified file1.html for both ticket 1 and ticket 2. Now we are asked to check in changes for ticket 1 only, and then I have to save a copy of file1.html outside of my solution and then determine what changes are for ticket 1 and remove those changes for ticket 2 before I check in. Pain!

What's your suggestion? What should I say to convince the team here to stop this check-in policy and allow us to check in as often as we want before it is QA'ed? Thanks!

Comment: How do your features actually get QA'd if you're not checking in the relevant code first?

Comment: Here we do it in a counter-productive way: We deploy to our dev environment IIS server directly from our dev box.  That's how the QA team gets to test.

Comment: If your changes aren't merged into the relevant TFS branch will they not be overwritten by the next person who deploys to the dev IIS server???

Comment: Very often, and that's exactly another issue!

Comment: Is there a TFS best practice article that's authoritative enough to convince the team that their policy needs to change?

Comment: Your situation seems to violate most common sense version control practices, so I'm not sure whether there will be an authoritative article on common sense practices in VCS environments.

Comment: I've indicated to them a while back that this policy is simply counter productive and needs to be changed.

Comment: To say the least: The version we deploy to our internal IIS server should be a build from TFS, not from each individual programmer's VS 2012.

Comment: I hate to say this, but if I were in your position I would be looking elsewhere for employment.

Comment: I totally understand because I've thought about it. However, I don't think I will. I am thinking about trying to persuade them to change. Every work place has its problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you seem to understand the problem fairly well, you just need to lay out the pros/cons of the two approaches.

- Error-prone to cherry-pick files to check-in at a later date
- The version/files you check-in may not match what QA tested.  Ideally QA should be testing the same code that will be release, and your version control system is used to enforce that.
- Having QA test code that included other changes that may or may not be in the same release can lead to test passes/failures that are dependent on code that will *not* be in the release.  This can invalidate the QA process.
- What you are doing is different than what most other teams are doing (honestly this usually resonates with managers more than the other points - in my experience as a consultant at least)

It sounds like what your team is trying to achieve is have a set of code that has all undergone QA and is "releasable" at any time.  This is a good goal, but it is usually achieved by using an appropriate branching strategy.

One approach is to do branch by feature (that's essentially what you're trying to do now, only without the support of a version control system).  This means you have a branch for each independent change/feature that you make.  QA happens against your feature branch.  Once QA passes that feature branch is merged into MAIN (aka trunk).

This way developers have their own feature branch that they can check-in to often (best practice is at least one check-in per day).  And you still have the copy of the code that is restricted to only code that has passed QA (MAIN), and is always release-ready.

If you fail to convince them you can also use a local Git repository to keep your personal changes organized, then use the Git-tfs tool to send them over to TFS when it's time to check-in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I was actually searching a Git-TFS solution a while back, but didn't know that such tools even exists. I was wondering though if I push my changes to git and then to TFS, will it carry something Git-ty to TFS?

Comment: I know lots of people that use Git-tfs to enable a local git repository with TFS backend.  It appears to work just fine, TFS (and other TFS users) don't even know your changes are coming from Git.  Alternatively, if you are using TFS 2013 you can have TFS use Git as the version control backend, then you don't need the Git-tfs tool to act as a bridge, and would have Git on both client and server.